# Migrate configuration OR entire collection from Lucidworks Fusion to "plain" Solr

Tags: solr, lucidworks

I used **Lucidworks Fusion** to parse a CSV file into a collection, where each row becomes one document, and string fields have both the _s and _t variant.

Now my Fusion demo license has expired.  I can still launch the embedded Solr, but I can't use Fusion's wizards to do tasks like parsing & indexing new data.  I know the parse I described above is pretty basic, but I don't do it very often.  I liked Fusion and might get a license some day, but not right now.

Can I install plain Solr, run it on a different port, and migrate this whole collection?  Or can I create a new collection in the plain Solr server, copy some configuration file from Fusion, and send a new CSV file over CURL or something like that?

Comment: Assuming you still have the CSV, then it's easier to just download Solr, create a collection and index the CSV into it. For configuration, I'm not sure how Fusion works but did you create the schema? Or is it just using something like a managed one with dynamic fields (that's what it seems like)? Either way, in Solr it's easy enough to index a CSV and use the header values for fields. It _does_ try to assume field types so you might need to tweak them, but that too is easy enough.

Comment: Trying to migrate over the configuration or the index itself will likely be harder than just doing it again in a plain, separate Solr instance. Also by doing it in Solr, you'll learn how to configure Solr and how to index stuff via curl using its API and so on,  so you'll be in better stead if you want to index new data, or tweak the text analytics, or whatever.